# In PDF, if Encoding and ToUnicode are both present in PDF, how to map the text extraction?

Tags: c++, c, pdf, qpdf

I used qpdf to uncompress a PDF file and below is the output. You  can see that there both, `encoding` and `ToUnicode`, are present. If there is only ToUnicode I know how to map individual characters with Cmap file. But if you see output of Content stream is following

```
Tf
0.999402 0 0 1 71.9995 759.561 Tm
[()-2.11826()-1.14177()2.67786()-2.11826()8.55269()-5.44998()-4.70186()2.67786()-2.32338()2.67786()12.679(   )-3.75591()9.73429()]TJ
```

in break-at  there are some garbage data that is not visible. So how to link data to cmap file ?

And one another question is that in `/Encoding` what are values contain in Difference ?

```
10 0 obj
<< /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Differences [ 1 /g100 /g28 /g94 /g3 /g87 /g24 /g38 /g47 /g62 ] /Type /Encoding >>
```

Even if I pass one by one values of Difference array into one of FreeType function is named as FT_Get_Name_Indek. This function return values like [ 100 28 94 3 87 24 38 47 62]

What is those values ? how to map those Value ?

[here is pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=57351764084853993971)

run following cmd

```
qpdf --stream-data=uncompress input.pdf output.text
```

[output.text](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00816919825132875377)

I got the same output if I pass contents stream data into zlib. kindly check output.txt file from link

Comment: *in break-at there are some garbag data that is not visible* - completely wrong. In the brackets there are the values identifying your glyphs, so they definitively are not garbage.

Comment: yes there are some value. i know while but in this case i didn't get the values..  using those values only we can map with CMap file..why i am not getting i don't know...please tell me if you know

Comment: i upload pdf file please kindly check out . you get know what i am traying to told you..    run this cmd    qpdf --stream-data=uncompress input.pdf  output.text   this cmd will give you output.text file that same file currently i displayed u above

Comment: Ah, that is your misunderstanding: `qpdf --stream-data=uncompress` does not give you a text file, you can merely recognise more of it in a text editor but it still is a binary file.

Comment: yes it give you. through that only i conclude.. and one more thing even i pass contents data see /Contents 5 0 R  into zlib .  i got same thing that  got from qpdf tool .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Firstly the general question

> #### how to exract the text in pdf if encoding and ToUnicode both are present in pdf? how to map it?
>
> [...] if you see there are encoding and ToUnicode both are present in pdf. i know if only ToUnicode is there so how to map individual char with Cmap file.

In such a case, i.e. when you have both a sufficiently complete and correct **ToUnicode** map and an **Encoding** for a font, *you can ignore the **Encoding** and only use the **ToUnicode** map.*

This follows from the PDF specification which in section 9.10.2 "Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values" states that the methods to map a character code to a Unicode value with the highest priority is

> If the font dictionary contains a ToUnicode CMap (see 9.10.3, "ToUnicode CMaps"), use that CMap to convert the character code to Unicode.

Thus, if you (as you say) already know how to extract text if there only is a **ToUnicode** map, you can use the same algorithm unchanged. And as a corollary, if that doesn't work, the **ToUnicode** map in question is insufficiently complete or incorrect, or your knowledge itself on how to extract text using only a **ToUnicode** map actually is incomplete.

#### Secondly the sample document

You wrote

> [()-2.11826()-1.14177()2.67786()-2.11826()8.55269()-5.44998()-4.70186()2.67786()-2.32338()2.67786()12.679( )-3.75591()9.73429()]TJ
>
> in break-at there are some garbag data that is not visible. so how to link data to cmap file ?

In the brackets there are the values identifying your glyphs, so **they definitively are not garbage.**

Thus, here are the byte values from within the brackets:

```
[(
    01
)-2.11826(
    02
)-1.14177(
    03
)2.67786(
    01
)-2.11826(
    04
)8.55269(
    05
)-5.44998(
    06
)-4.70186(
    07
)2.67786(
    04
)-2.32338(
    07
)2.67786(
    08
)12.679(
    09
)-3.75591(
    02
)9.73429(
    04
)]TJ
```

Using the **ToUnicode** map of the font in question

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00><ff>
endcodespacerange
9 beginbfrange
<01><01><0054>
<02><02><0045>
<03><03><0053>
<04><04><0020>
<05><05><0050>
<06><06><0044>
<07><07><0046>
<08><08><0049>
<09><09><004c>
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end end
```

the byte values from within the brackets map to:

```
    01    0054    "T"
    02    0045    "E"
    03    0053    "S"
    01    0054    "T"
    04    0020    " "
    05    0050    "P"
    06    0044    "D"
    07    0046    "F"
    04    0020    " "
    07    0046    "F"
    08    0049    "I"
    09    004c    "L"
    02    0045    "E"
    04    0020    " "
```

Thus,

```
"TEST PDF FILE "
```

which matches the rendered file just fine:

[image: Screenshot]

#### Thirdly the encoding

> and one another question is that in /Encoding what are values contain in Difference ?
>
> 10 0 obj << /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Differences [ 1 /g100 /g28 /g94 /g3 /g87 /g24 /g38 /g47 /g62 ] /Type /Encoding >>

According to the PDF specification,

> The value of the **Differences** entry shall be an array of character codes and character names organized as follows:
>
> *code*<sub>1</sub> *name*<sub>1,1</sub> *name*<sub>1,2</sub> …
>
> *code*<sub>2</sub> *name*<sub>2,1</sub> *name*<sub>2,2</sub> …
>
> …
>
> *code*<sub>n</sub> *name*<sub>n,1</sub> *name*<sub>n,2</sub> …
>
> Each code shall be the first index in a sequence of character codes to be changed. The first character name after the code becomes the name corresponding to that code. Subsequent names replace consecutive code indices until the next code appears in the array or the array ends. These sequences may be specified in any order but shall not overlap.

Thus, the encoding entry in your case says that the encoding basically is **WinAnsiEncoding** with the difference that the codes 1, ..., 9 instead represent the glyphs named /g100, /g28, /g94, /g3, /g87, /g24, /g38, /g47, and /g62 respectively.

As these glyph names are no standard glyph names, the PDF specification does not consider this encoding helpful for text extraction because it only describes a method for a simple font

> that has an encoding whose **Differences** array includes only character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters in the Symbol font (see Annex D)

The "/gXX" names in your sample clearly are not among them.

Comment: Hi, i too have used qpdf to uncompress one of my pdf file.
but i cannot understand what my content is.
I have a ToUnicode in the uncompressed file - https://pastebin.com/mfznMhm6

i used qpdf -qdf option

can i get the content of the file ?

Comment: *"i cannot understand what my content is"* - You should study the PDF specification to understand what you see. If you have specific questions (*"i cannot understand what my content is"* is not specific at all), create detailed stack overflow questions for them.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth observing that most of the time the `/Encoding` map is a *character codes* (intended as the encoded bytes of a string) to *CID* map, where *CID* (Character ID) in most font types corresponds to a glyph index/identifier. The exception appears to with *Type2* fonts which have separate *CID* and *GID* (Glyph ID) concepts, supplying a `/CIDToGIDMap` to convert between them. In the above cases the `/Encoding` map has nothing to do with decoding an *Unicode* representation of the string. To decode the Unicode representation you definitely should use the `/ToUnicode` when available, as pointed bt @mkl. If it is not available, you are in one case where you either have a predefined encoding (optionally with a `/Difference` map) or *CMap*, or you a in a case where the font program supplies an implicit encoding, like in *Type1* fonts. This is all stated in the very good @mkl [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26910569/213871) as well. `/Encoding` could possibly corresponds to the map to convert between the *character codes* and Unicode *code points* when it's either a predefined encoding (like **MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, but I also saw use of possibly non compliant **Identity-H**, which is a predefined *CMap* name, not a predefined encoding) or in a supposedly malformed font. With this regard PDF reference/standard is often confusing about what is legal and what is not, so a library decoding encoded strings in PDF should always be as lenient as possible. Also the PDF reference/standard itself is not much clear in explaining the distinction between *character codes*, *CID*, *GID* and *Unicode* representations.